# Whats the fastest way in Java to form a collection of objects that match a collection of predicates?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, predicate

Consider a collection of objects and a collection of predicates, whats the fastest way to form a collection of predicates object pairs, where each pair is an object and a predicate which returns true.

Also objects must be unique across pairs, but this does not apply to predicates.

I.e. consider objects A, B, and C, and predicates P1, P2, P3

(A,P1),(B,P1),(C,P2) is a valid set of pairs, however
(A,P1),(A,P1),(C,P2) is a not valid as there are duplicate objects across pairs

So once a predicate is matched to an object it effectively owns it.

I.e. whats the fastest way to implement the method below given the constraints above:

```
Collection<Pair<Object,Predicate<Object>> getAllMatches(Collection<Object> objects, Collection<Predicate<Object>>);
```

where Pair is:

```
class Pair<A,B> {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

I know I'd need to use multi-threading but I'm not sure of the best strategy or the best collection implementations to use. Also I imagine the uniqueness contraint will introduce contention due to the need for some sort of locking or ownership mechanism.

Heres my attempt, it seems to basic, surely there must be a faster way:

```
  Collection<Pair<Object,Predicate> getAllMatches(BlockingQueue<Object> objects, Collection<Predicate> predicates){
List<Callable<Pair>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object o : objects){
    Callable<Pair> c = ()-> {
        Object polled = objects.take();
        for (Predicate p : predicates){
            if (p.test(polled)){
                return new Pair<Object,Predicate>(o,p);
            }
        }
        objects.put(o);
        return null;
    }
    callables.add(c);
}
List<Future<Pair>> futurePairs = exectors.invokeAll(callables);

 // return pairs
}
```

Comment: To do this, you need to write some code. When you have written some, and if you have a problem with it, please edit the question to add the details.

Comment: In general the naive solution (iterate the cross product) is the only solution. Just make the collections duplicate free before this. You can speed up with multithreading over predicates or objects.

Comment: @Bohemian sure, I have provided an attempt.

Comment: @Coron yes I'm aware of that solution but what about the contention issues?

Comment: Multithreading only makes sense if evaluating each predicate takes long. Otherwise, a simple sequential solution would have no overhead and would be much simpler. But in your parallel solution, you are evaluating predicates for an object sequentially, so you are losing the opportunity to parallelize to a maximum extent. This would be especially meaningful if evaluating each predicate is I/O bounded.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner could you provide an example? Also on a multi processor / multi-core system surely you would get a speed up even if the predicates do not take long, as the iterations will be split across those resources.

Comment: The example I was thinking of is like the first snippet in @Andrew 's answer. Just iterate over the objects, then a nested loop with the predicates, check if the predicate succeeds and go on with the next object. And don't be so sure about the speed up in a multi-core system, because the overhead is always important: you need to measure and benchmark carefully before arriving to such conclusions.

Comment: Performance probably depends on the size of both sets. Smaller sizes will produce too much overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Your benchmark should absolutely be:

```
final Collection<Pair<Object, Predicate>> getMatches(
        final Collection<Object> objects, 
        final Collection<Predicate> predicates) {
    final Set<Pair<Object, Predicate>> matches = new HashSet<>();
    for (Object o : objects) {
        for (Predicate p : predicates) {
            if (p.test(o)) {
                matches.add(Pair.with(o, p));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Sequential execution is *often* fastest. It may seem counter-intuitive - running tests on multiple cores *should* be fastest - but for many operations, your bottleneck is actually going to be memory-access. Each processor is going to stall, doing nothing, while it verifies that it's processor-level-cache is consistent with all of the other processors' caches.

I'd propose *testing* something like this, if you're confident that multithreading is going to save you some time:

```
final Collection<Pair<Object, Predicate>> getMatches(
        final Collection<Object> objects, 
        final Collection<Predicate> predicates) {
    final List<Future<Pair<Object,Predicate>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Object o : objects) {
        futures.add(executorService.invoke(() -> {
            for (Predicate p : predicates) {
                if (p.test(o)) {
                    return Pair.with(o, p);
                }
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
    final Collection<Pair<Object,Predicate>> matches = new ArrayList<>(futures.size());
    for (final Future<Pair<Object,Predicate>> future : futures) {
        final Pair<Object,Predicate> pair = future.get();
        if (pair != null) {
            matches.add(pair);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

None of the threads *write* to shared memory, so there is no lock-contention to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overcomplicating this a bit.  Stream over objects and for each object find a predicate that matches it:

```
objects.stream()    // or parallelStream() for multithreaded
    .distinct()     // can omit this if uniqueness of objects is enforced elsewhere
    .flatMap(obj -> predicates.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.test(obj))
        .map(p -> new Pair<>(obj, p))
        .limit(1)   // one predicate per object
    ).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Nice job! The `limit(1)` is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

A short solution with Java8 streams using declarative parallelism:

```
Collection<Pair<Object, Predicate<Object>>> getAllMatches(Set<Object> objects, Set<Predicate<Object>> predicates) {
    List<Pair<Object, Predicate<Object>>> pairs = predicates.parallelStream()
        .map(predicate -> new Pair<>(objects.stream().filter(predicate), predicate))
        .flatMap(pair -> pair.a.map(a -> new Pair<>(a, pair.b)))
        .collect(toList());
    return pairs;
}
```

Parallel execution is managed by the stream:

```
    List<Pair<Object, Predicate<Object>>> pairs = predicates.parallelStream()
```

The next line creates a Pair (the stream contains all matching objects):

```
        .map(predicate -> new Pair<>(objects.stream().filter(predicate), predicate))
```

The next line flattens to Pair:

```
        .flatMap(pair -> pair.a.map(a -> new Pair<>(a, pair.b)))
```

The last line creates the final collection:

```
        .collect(toList());
```

If `objects` or `predicates` are not free of duplicates, put `.distinct()` behind `stream()` or `parallelStream()`.